# How to get the direct file url of live broadcast video in youtube

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube

there are two kind of videos in youtube, one is "Live broadcast" and the other is not.
I can get the direct file link of none live broadcast video and streaming on my iphone but the "Live broadcast" is not working.

there is a picture of "Live broadcast" on youtube  (www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-VrwrEntWY)
[image]

I have used js(parse the url to get direct file's url) with JSContext(objective-c) to do the streaming on my ios app. 
Please help me out here, I need a js example which can really parse the "Live broadcast" video of youtube, or
is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Refer the [https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) in that you can add filter parameter **eventType=live**, then you will get all **LIVE** videos.